# Java method that accepts multiple types as a single parameter

Tags: java, generics, types

Suppose I have two custom classes and a method as follows:

```
class A {
  public void think() {
    // do stuff
  }
}

class B {
  public void think() {
    // do other stuff
  }
}

Class C {
  public void processStuff(A thinker) {
    thinker.think();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to write `processStuff()`as anything like this (just illustrating):

```
public void processStuff({A || B} thinker) {...}
```

Or, in other words, is there a way to write a method with a one parameter that accepts multiple types, as to avoid typing the `processStuff()` method multiple times?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define the behavior you want in an interface, have `A` and `B` implement the interface, and declare your `processStuff` to take as an argument an instance of the interface.

```
interface Thinker {
    public void think();
}

class A implements Thinker {
    public void think() { . . .}
}

class B implements Thinker {
    public void think() { . . .}
}

class C {
    public void processStuff(Thinker thinker) {
        thinker.think();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any workaround for the scenario where class A and B are not in our control, (i.e. available as part of external library) ?

Comment: @phantomastray - Well, you can define wrapper classes. For example: `class WrapperA implements Thinker { private final A a; public WrapperA(A a) { this.a = a; } public void think() { /* think with a */ } }` (and similarly for B). Then you could pass around wrapper class instances instead of the external library class instances. It's not a complete work-around (you still can't pass an `A` or `B` to `processStuff`) but maybe it will get you part of the way to what you need. Post a question with a specific use case might get you better advice.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the simplest is to define an interface

```
interface Thinker {
   public void think();
}
```

then let your classes implement it :

```
class A implements Thinker {
  public void think() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

and use it as parameter type :

```
Class C {
  public void processStuff(Thinker t) {
    t.think();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Define `Thinker` as an interface:

```
public interface Thinker
{
    public void think();
}
```

Then have classes `A` and `B` implement it:

```
public class A
implements Thinker
```

And finally, define `processStuff()` to take a `Thinker` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a common interface containing the `think` method, and let `A` and `B` implement it.

Or you could overload `processStuff()` and have two implementations, each taking one of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could simply use Polymorphism. To do this you overload your methods-- create methods that have the same name, but different parameter types. java does not check method names, it checks method signatures(a methods name+parameter+return type) for example:

```
public class foo
{
       public int add(int a, int b)
       {
            int sum = a+b ;
            return sum ; 
       }


       public String add(String a, String b)
       {
            String sum = a+b ;
            return sum ; 
       }

       public static void main(String args[])
       {
            foo f = new foo() ;
            System.out.printf("%s\n",f.add("alpha","bet));
            System.out.printf("%d", f.add(1,2);
       }


 }
```

this code should return

```
alphabet
3
```

as you can see the two method signatures are different, so there is no error.
please note this is JUST an EXAMPLE of what COULD be done.