# implement a typed list List<SomeThing>

Tags: java

Apologies for the title, I'm not quite sure what it should be.

I'm new to Java and have inherited a codebase with the following pattern:

```
public abstract class BaseThing{...}

public class ThingA extends BaseThing{
    public List<BaseThing> elements;
}

public class ThingB extends BaseThing{
    public List<BaseThing> elements;
}

public class ThingC extends BaseThing{...}

public class ThingD extends BaseThing{...}
```

I want to write a method that works on BaseThing(s) that have an elements property e.g. ThingA and ThingB.

[A Java method that accepts multiple types as a single parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978936/java-method-that-accepts-multiple-types-as-a-single-parameter) is similar to what I want to achieve, however the interface is for a method instead of a property. I don't think it's possible with properties on an interface.

I also looked at method overloading, however it doesn't appear to scale well, I'd need to add a new method every time a new ThingX is created.

What is the Java way of achieving this?

Comment: Can you modify the existing classes? If yes then the obious choice would be to create a common superclass for ThingA and ThingB and put your List in that class.

Comment: Either create a common super class that has `elements` or create an interface with a `getElements()` method, and have ThingA and ThingB implement that interface.

Comment: You should never cast to an `abstract` class to manipulating an `abstract` class directly is one of most extreme *code smells* that should tell you that you are *doing it wrong*. An interface or a common concrete implementation is what you should use.

Comment: Just reproduce what you provide as example

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Is adding additional hierarchy better in this instance than introducing an interface?

Comment: @MarkB In this instance, is there a preferred approach? I'm inclined to use an interface instead of introducing more hierachy.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome I'm not too sure what you mean, can you point me to a better pattern? Just to clarify, I didn't write this, I inherited it from experienced Java developers

Comment: If you inherited this from *experienced* developers, I wonder what their *experience* is in, because it is **not** in correctly applied idiomatic OOA/OOD or Java. The duplicate explains everything that can be explained about this very clearly, anything else beyond that is **Too Broad** for StackOveflow. Every comment says exactly what the duplicate and my comment say.  Get one of those *experienced* Java developers to explain the comments and the duplicate to you in person. The "Related" column of the duplicates have even more duplicates listed.

Comment: @StephenS I would probably prefer the interface in this instance as well. It's difficult to say without knowing exactly what these objects represent and without a deeper understanding of your business and problem domain, but in general I would change the `elements` property to private, and have these classes implement an interface with a `getElements()` method (and a `setElements()` method if you need that).

Comment: @MarkB Thanks, I'll go the interface route. The getElements setElements method is going to have the same implementation for each class that implements it. I take it there's no way to avoid duplicating the code? I looked in to interface default methods, however I can't see how a getter/setter could be used.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome My understanding was that they were experienced, however from your comments it appears that might not be the case. Not that I could, but I'm guessing the original developers wouldn't be the best people to ask. For my own clarification, is the main issue here that each class extends an abstract class?

Comment: @StephenS if you want to implement the getters/setters in one place, due to the fact you'd have to create a private member `elements` variable, you would have to do that via a base class instead of an interface.